# WebMethod Ajax Call 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I am trying to create a webform that will send an email when submitted. I created a webmethod and am trying to post with ajax. My ajax is 404ing when I submit. Here is my code. I am a beginner when it comes to .net, and am trying to play around a bit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.validate-form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var first_name = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var last_name = document.getElementById("last_name").value;

    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var data = "{'first name': '" + first_name + "', 'last name': '" + last_name + "', 'fromEmail': '" + 
               email + "'}";
    console.log("data", data)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SendMessage.aspx/SendMessages",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
    })
});
```

```csharp
public partial class Send : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static void SendMessages(string first_name, string last_name, string email, string comments)
    {

        const string SERVER = "zebra.aa.org";
        const string TOEMAIL = "adhsaj@am.org";
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(email);
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(TOEMAIL);
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

        message.Subject = "Web Site Contact Inquiry from " + first_name + last_name;
        message.Body = "Message from: " + first_name + last_name + " at " +
                       email + "\n\n" + comments;
        message.IsBodyHtml = false;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(SERVER);
        client.Send(message);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your webmethod is looking for 'SendMessage.aspx' but it looks like your page might ne just named 'Send'? `public partial class Send : System.Web.UI.Page`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is the URL. The client cannot find the web method because the URL doesn't exist. Try changing

```
url: "SendMessage.aspx/SendMessages"
```

to

```
url: "Send/SendMessages"
```

Comment: I tried changing it to the suggested URL, but it still 404s. My form is in SendMessage.aspx, and my backend code is in SendMessage.aspx.cs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your URl to `Send.aspx/SendMessages`

Also it would be better to use

```
JSON.stringify({ first_name : first_name, last_name : last_name, email : email, comments : comments })
```

You are not passing the required data in the format in which the method needs it. For instance I see that the first parameter is first_name on the aspx method but your JSON has a space in the characters. Please correct this as well and check.

Comment: Updated URL didn't work, and fixed JSON. Decided to take a different approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the URL and it seems fine, then probably the route configuration is messing with your ajax calls. You have to add this to the `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.Ignore("{page}.aspx/{*webmethod}");
```